# Cursor jumps after a lag in typing in VSCode Insiders

Tags: visual-studio-code

Has anyone seen this? It seems so huge I hesitate to report a bug.

When two or more TypeScript files are open, then when typing and after a very short lag, the cursor jumps to the beginning of what I believe is the AST node.

So if I start typing at the end of a function, after few keystrokes the cursor jumps to just before the `function` keyword. At the end of a statement, it jumps to its beginning and so on.

I've tried reinstalling insider builds back to June 14. No change. I can repro running `code-insiders --disable-extensions`.

I have my trackpad disabled, so it isn't due to my wrist accidentally touching it. I only see this in VS Code and only for languages that expose a syntax tree -- TypeScript, CSS, HTML for example, but not Groovy.

Any ideas would be very helpful!

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385772/vs-code-cursor-jumping-to-bottom?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are running into this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52080

It should already be fixed in the latest insiders build

Comment: Fantastic [Matt Bierner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306149/matt-bierner)! I searched the VSCode issues, but obviously not hard enough!

Comment: I've updated to Insiders 1.34.0 and see this bug now.