# VS Code cursor jumping to bottom

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why does my cursor jump to the last line of code when I create new tags? For example, when I type a comment in HTML, as soon as I type the !, it jumps to the bottom. What setting do I have to change to prevent this from happening? It is very annoying. I am just starting to use VS Code so sorry if this is a really simple fix.

Comment: That is not default behavior. Have you tried removing any installed extensions?

Comment: If you're an Angular developer, maybe consider disabling "Angular Essentials" Extension by "John Papa".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The `Flow Language Support` extension was causing it. I disabled it, and then the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I first started using vscode.

**Explanation**

Generally, the issue is caused by an extension of some sort that is messing with your IDE. Like the extension is trying to do its job but either there is a conflict with other extensions or vscode settings or that's how it works.
More specifically, I found the issue was caused by the the HTML, CSS, JS formatter extension.

**Solution**

If you have that extension, try disabling it and restart vscode. if the issue is fixed then you may leave it disabled or uninstall it. If it is not solved repeat the process with other extensions, especially those that format your code, until you find the culprit and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an Angular developer, maybe consider disabling `Angular Essentials` Extension by "John Papa". Then restart VS Code.
That worked for me after several frustrations.

Answer (score 0):

It *could be* that `Auto Scroll` is enabled (`Ctrl+Shift+P` then type autoscroll). This feature force scrolls to the bottom. Try disabling it.

Answer (score -1):

Also i got this type of issue.The solution is just disable your auto save it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).